# Checking out a particular revision of a Git repo via CMake

Tags: git, mercurial, cmake

CMake supports checking out git and mercurial repositories through the following components:

1. http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module:FindGit
2. http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module:FindHg

but the problem is that, while mercurial supports directly checking out a specific revision, git does not (one must checkout the repository, move into the folder, and then checkout the revision).

This is problematic because I develop a chain of libraries, where each builds on top of the last, and so it is useful for me to be able to have library B check out the last compatible revision of upstream library A. This was one command with FindHg.

What is the pragmatic way to mirror this functionality with git?

Comment: Have you tried the `--branch` option of `git clone`?

Comment: I apologize, my wording was muddled. I am trying to check out a specific revision rather than a specific branch.

Comment: It seems you can specify also a tag name with `--branch`.

Comment: Wouldn't this still require me to make changes in upstream library A any time I update the downstream library B?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The --branch option of git clone
>
> You can specify a tag name to check out a specific revision